# IIS 10 URL Rewrite 2.1 can't rewrite to asmx

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, asmx

I've configured a rewrite rule in IIS to basically rewrite the request from http://mydomain to http://mydomain/subfolder/mywebservice.asmx and I can verify that the rewrite triggers and rewrites correctly.

However the problem is that once it's rewritten I get an IIS error "**The file extension for the requested URL does not have a handler configured to process the request on the Web server.**"

When I navigate directly to http://mydomain/subfolder/mywebservice.asmx it works and the .asmx extension is handled correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the Application Request Routing extension. All that was required was to install ARR, then enable the proxy and the rewrite rules started resolving properly.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing